# Why am I getting overexposure with only one lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting, overexposure

I am having an issue with my Nikon D300s.  When using a Nikkor 70-300mm lens and a Nikkor 75-200mm lens, my pictures are fine.  However, when using the same body and switching to a Nikkor 28-80mm lens, the viewfinder appears dark, and the pictures taken are very bright.  I am assuming this is a lens issue.  I was wondering if this is something that can be fixed or if I need to replace the lens?

I apologize if I am missing technical information.  I am still learning the camera.

Comment: Which 28-80mm lens are you using? The G lens or the D lens?

Comment: There are two different versions of the 28-80mm f/3.5-5.6 AF-D. From 1995-1999 Nikon sold one with only 7 elements. From 1999-2001 they made a different lens with the same name that had 8 elements.

Answer (score 6):

It is very likely that the aperture linkage is broken.

The aperture is held closed by the spring until the objective is mounted, after that it is held opened by the camera so that the viewfinder is bright and is stopped down for each exposure.

If the linkage is broken the viewfinder will be dark and the camera won't know about it and will overexpose as much as you stop the aperture down: it probably won't underexpose at 28mm/F3,5 and will overexpose bigly at 28mm/F16 (~8 stops).

The actual aperture will of course not be F3,5.